# Is my SSD runing AHCI mode?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, bios, sata

So I switched my BIOS setting from IDE to AHCI, and when I booted up in windows 7 it reinstalled the drivers for my SSD. But I can't seem to find if it's currently running in AHCI mode or not. I've googled how to check if it's in AHCI mode, and see that there is supposed to be an ACHI device under DEVICE MANAGER - IDE ATA/ATAPI controllers. But in my device manager there is only an AMD SATA Controller. When I click properties on that, and Details and check the service, it says only AMDSATA:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j0Kvz.png]

When I use AS SSD Benchmark it says neither pciide, msahci or iastor, but instead the AMDSATA - OK in green.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNOYZ.png]

But how can I know if this AMDSATA driver is in IDE or AHCI mode?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the SSD runs in AHCI mode. Take a look at the 2nd picture and here you can see amdsata. This is AHCI. In IDE mode you see in read PCIIDE:

[image]